# A question about the existence of

Tags: number-theory

Maybe a stupid question: 
Let $p_1,p_2,p_3$ be prime numbers and $0\leq x_1<p_2$, $0\leq x_2<p_1$,$0\leq x_3<p_3$. If $x_1$ is fixed, is there exist such $x_2,x_3$ satisfying that
$x_1p_1+x_2p_2+x_3p_1p_2=kp_3 \mod p_1p_2p_3$ for some $k$ that $0\leq k<p_1p_2p_3$ ($k$ can be any value as you choose in the domain $0\leq k<p_1p_2p_3$).  If so, i further need to know that, if $x_1$ is fixed, are $x_2,x_3,k$ fixed? Let me give a example: let $p_1=2,p_2=3,p_3=5$, then we set $x_1=1,x_2=1,x_3=0$, we have: $1\cdot2+1\cdot3+0\cdot6=5$. I wonder the above solution, i.e., $x_1=1,x_2=1,x_3=0$, when $x_1=1$ is fixed, is unique or not.

If above holds, could anyone give me a simplified proof (or proof sketch)? Thanks very much!

Comment: You should know, a trivial solution is $x_1=x_2=x_3=k=0$.  You may want to add the condition that $x_1 \neq 0$

Comment: Also posted to (and put on hold at) MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/241800/a-question-about-the-existence-of-a-function

Answer (score 1):

I assume the $p_i$ are meant to be distinct.  Let $y_i$ satisfy $$-x_1p_1 \equiv y_1 \mod p_1$$ $$-x_1p_1 \equiv y_2 \mod p_2$$ $$-x_1p_1 \equiv y_3 \mod p_3 \\$$Clearly $y_1 \equiv 0 \mod p_1$

Denote by $(a^{-1})_b$ the multiplicative inverse of $a \mod b$.  Then using the Chinese Remainder Theorem:

$-x_1p_1 \equiv \left[y_2p_1(p_1^{-1})_{p_2}(p_3^{-1})_{p_1p_2}\right]p_3+\left[y_3(p_1p_2)_{p_3}^{-1}\right]p_1p_2 \mod p_1p_2p_3$

Setting $k=-y_2p_1(p_1^{-1})_{p_2}(p_3^{-1})_{p_1p_2}$ and choosing any $x_2$ and $x_3$ satisfying $x_2'+x_3=y_3(p_1p_2)_{p_3}^{-1}$, where $x_2=x_2'p_1$, should solve it.

---

Here's some more details on how I came up with that construction.  $$-x_1p_1 \equiv y_1 \mod p_1$$ $$-x_1p_1 \equiv y_2 \mod p_2$$

implies $$-x_1p_1 \equiv y_1p_2(p_2^{-1})_{p_1}+y_2p_1(p_1^{-1})_{p_2} \mod p_1p_2$$

by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Thus, $$-x_1p_1 \equiv y_2p_1(p_1^{-1})_{p_2} \mod p_1p_2$$ $$-x_1p_1 \equiv y_3 \mod p_3 $$

so again by the Chinese Remainder Theorem,

$-x_1p_1 \equiv \left[y_2p_1(p_1^{-1})_{p_2}\right]p_3(p_3^{-1})_{p_1p_2}+\left[y_3\right](p_1p_2)(p_1p_2)_{p_3}^{-1} \mod p_1p_2p_3 \Rightarrow $

$-x_1p_1 \equiv \left[y_2p_1(p_1^{-1})_{p_2}(p_3^{-1})_{p_1p_2}\right]p_3+\left[y_3(p_1p_2)_{p_3}^{-1}\right]p_1p_2 \mod p_1p_2p_3 \Rightarrow$

$-x_1p_1 \equiv -kp_3+(x_2'+x_3)p_1p_2 \mod p_1p_2p_3 \Rightarrow$

$kp_3 \equiv x_1p_1+x_2'p_1p_2+x_3p_1p_2 \mod p_1p_2p_3 \Rightarrow$

$kp_3 \equiv x_1p_1+x_2p_2+x_3p_1p_2 \mod p_1p_2p_3$

Comment: Dear JasonM: I am the questioner, and I am not familiar with using the Stack Exchange. It is my pleasure to receive your detailed answer. Thanks very much! Your answer is very interesting. However, I have a little suspect about the unique of the solution. There is a limitation that $0<x_1<p_2,0\leq x_2<p_1$. It seems that you do not use this condition, or I have not fully catch up what you said? If $0<x_1<p_2,0\leq x_2<p_1$ and $x_1$ is fixed, then the solution is unique or not?

Comment: In my last section, it can be taken as $x_2' \equiv x_2\pm p_1p_3 \mod p_2$, $x_3' \equiv x_3 \pm p_3 \mod p_1p_2$, and $k' \equiv k \pm p_1p_2 \mod p_3$.  That should fix your concern.

Comment: Also, if you'd be so kind to accept my answer, it would be greatly appreciated. It's the star under the arrows near the top of my comment.

Comment: Dear JasonM: Thanks very much again! However, if $x'_2=x_2\pm p_1p_3$ as you said, how can you guarantee that this "$x'_2$ family" have more than one $x'_2$ in the domain of [0,p_1)?  e.g., let $x_2=2,p_1=5,p_3=7$ , it seems that only $x_2=2$ can be the unique solution in the domain $[0,4)$...

Comment: The only way $k' \equiv k \mod p_2$ is if $p_1p_3 \equiv 0 \mod p_2$, which since I assumed these primes are distinct, this cannot happen

Comment: @dengyuqiao You seem to have two accounts at Mathematica.SE: [user40893](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/40893/user40893) (unregistered) and [dengyuqiao](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/40894/dengyuqiao). The first one is the account which asked this question before it was migrated to this site. If you have access to both of them, you can [merge the two accounts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/merge-accounts/info). Then you should be able to comment on any answer to your question.

Comment: Dear JasonM: I have clicked the upper arrow for your answer. I don't know what else i can do to recommend your answer. It is really a very distinguished answer!

Comment: Dear JasonM: Note that  the condition is $x_2 \in [0,p_1)$ but not $x_2 \in [0,p_2)$, it seems that if you let  $x'_2=x_2\pm p_1p_3 \mod p_2$, then the $p_1p_3$ part will "eliminate"?

Comment: @dengyuqiao Ah, well in that case, $x_2$ does seem to be unique, though I haven't checked it in depth.  I will edit my answer.  Another interesting problem would be to show that if $x_2 \in [0, p_2)$, then this method yields $\italics{all}$ solutions.  I'm not sure if it's true.  Is there not a check mark under the arrows?  It helps give me a decent amount of reputation if you check it.